# Входная строка имела неверный формат PascalABC

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

В программу вводится строка чисел, разделённых плюсами, типа '123+456+789+456'. Результат работы программы - столб чисел, присутствующих в троке, игнорируя последнее, типа 
'123
456
789'
Помогите! Правильно выводит 2 числа, а потом пишет 'Входная строка имела неверный формат, ошибка: строка 24'

```
 uses crt;
var
sumi:array [1..10] of real;
i,l,posit,d,n,f:integer;
c,a,b:real; s:string[100];sums,chsl:string;
begin
n:=0;
read (s);
l:=(ord(s[0]));
posit:=Pos ('+',s);
while posit<>0 do begin
  sums:='';
  chsl:='';
  posit:=Pos ('+',s);
  n:=n+1;
  if posit=1 then
  delete (s,1,1) else begin
  For i:=1 to (posit-1) do begin
    chsl:=s[1];
    sums:=sums+chsl;
    delete (s,1,1);
    end;
    sumi[n]:=strtofloat(sums);
    delete (s,1,1);
  writeln('!',sumi[n]);
  end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: `posit:=Pos ('+',s);` в теле цикла надо перенести в его конец, иначе вы сначала проверяете наличие плюсов в строке, а потом их оттуда удаляете.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло. Впредь буду внимательнее.)

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж упомянули **PascalABC.NET**, вот альтернатива Вашему коду:

```
## ReadString.Split('+')[:^1].PrintLines(s -> '!'+s)
```